# I have created the Maven project in command line and But getting below errors.Please help me here

Tags: eclipse, maven

Error 1:
CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.8.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.8.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000  pom.xml /consumerBanking    line 6  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your local maven repository (`C:\Users\username\.m2\`) and create a project again.

Comment: I deleted the folder and again i have created but showing same errosr in JBDS IDE